# How to leverage multicore CPUs when compiling C# projects in a large solution?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, msbuild

As far as I know, VS2008/MSBuild do not suport multithreaded compilation of C# projets. I don't know if VS2010 supports it. Do you know a 3rd party product or an open source projet that does that?

Comment: http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2007/11/msbuild-multithreaded-building-in.html ?

Comment: No, I mean the build process itself. I want to compile multiple projects at the same time to have shorter build times when building a complex solution (80+ projects)

Comment: @James Kolpack, the OP is asking about the build itself, not the language.

Comment: You might consider a clearer title, "How to leverage multicore CPU's when compiling C#?"

Comment: Yes, I figured out the OP's intention after realizing the way I had read it was absurd.

Comment: @James, this is only supported for C++ projects. But Snorfus provided a link on how to make it work for C#. I'll test that and will get back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed MSBuild [does support multiple cores](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx); though it's a bit of a hack with some limitations.

It's easier [from the commandline](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx).

Likewise, some build servers (teamcity is one if I recall) can have build runners on multiple machines to further reduce build times.

Comment: OMG! What a difference. Thanks a million! For others not feeling like reading the aforementioned articles: `MSBuild.exe /m YourSolution.sln`. The `/m` option is the key...