# Compiling a large C# solution? (4.5 million LOC)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, compilation

What is the standard process for compiling large Visual Studio C# projects in the millions of lines of code?

I attempted to build my current project with Visual Studio 2010 on a machine with a quad-core i7 and 8 GB RAM, but it froze the UI for two days before crashing and failing to output the intended DLL. Similar results have been duplicated with this project on multiple machines, so it doesn't seem to be an issue localised to my box. I notice that devenv has a `/build` switch, so I'll try that tonight; is this likely to succeed, or is there something else I should try?

Edit: Seems I should try [`MSBuild.exe /m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582170/459881).

Comment: Why do you have such a huge project in one dll?

Comment: I would certainly think a build script or non-GUI build process of some sort is the general way to do this.

Comment: I'm going for the SSD drive and the [compile c# for multiple processorPC's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222798/how-to-compile-c-sharp-for-multiple-processor-machines-with-vs-2010-or-csc-exe). Out of curiosity what is the size of the copmiled files?

Comment: I have to agree with Dani; that much code sounds like a good candidate for breaking down into logical chunks that can go into separate dlls.

Comment: I could break it down, but only at the cost of extra complexity; the project fits logically together and would be a pain to work with if split up, so I'd prefer to keep it in one solution and library if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the link Jeremy, but it seems that what you posted is related to compiling for multiple cores rather than with multiple cores. As specified in my original post, the project failed to compile, so I can't really tell you what the size of the compiled file is...

Comment: Are you using Resharper? If so, go to the Resharper options and find a "show memory usage". This options displays the memory that Resharper is using. I often find it using 1GB on a much smaller project and restart VS. I do not know ... but it may be part of the problem.

Comment: How did you write it?
When you write code you are usually compiling and checking (read building) it constantly. Was there a point in time where the build succeeded through the UI?

Comment: 4.5M lines of code shouldn't logically 'fit together'. Modules of this size are almost impossible to manage interlectually. I bet that it is really hard to make changes to that code base. Take a step back and take a look at your architecture. Such big code base must be split up in multiple Modules.

Comment: No, not exactly; it's all generated code needed to properly interface with another piece of software. It was all created at the same time in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the UI hangs - without going into WinDbg - compile the DLL with the [C# Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)